# How to prove a block matrix is positive definite?

Tags: matrices, positive-definite, block-matrices, matrix-analysis

Suppose there is a Hermitian matrix $W\in\mathbb{C}^{mn\times mn}$ with size $mn\times mn$.
Denote $W_{ij}$ as the submatrix with size $n\times n$ in the following position:
\begin{equation}
W=\begin{bmatrix}
W_{11}& W_{12} &\cdots &W_{1m}\\
W_{21} &W_{22} &\cdots &W_{2m}\\
\vdots &\vdots &\ddots &\vdots \\
W_{m1}& W_{m2}& \cdots &W_{mm}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

$W_{ij}$ is known to be Hermitian and positive semi-definite. What kind of condition can guarantee that $W$ is positive definite?

Do we have some results like if $W_{ii}\succ \sum_{j\neq i}W_{ij} $ for each $i$, then $W$ is positive definite?

Comment: The block form of the Gershgorin circle theorem provides one sufficient condition along the lines of what you are thinking. https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82483704.pdf

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I will try to work based on this result. But the matrix norm is not always easily obtained and will not make full use of the Hermitian property of blocks. I still wonder if there any other paths based on the Loewner partial order rather than analysis based on matrix norm .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is sufficient. Let $P_i=W_{ii}-\sum_{j\ne i}W_{ij}$. Then
\begin{aligned}
W=\,&\pmatrix{P_1\\ &P_2\\ &&\ddots\\ &&&\ddots\\ &&&&P_m}\\
&+\pmatrix{W_{12}&W_{12}\\ W_{12}&W_{12}\\ \\ \\ &&&&}
+\pmatrix{W_{13}&&W_{13}\\ \\ W_{13}&&W_{13}\\ \\ &&&&}+\cdots
+\pmatrix{\\ \\ \\ &&&W_{m-1,m}&W_{m-1,m}\\ &&&W_{m-1,m}&W_{m-1,m}}.
\end{aligned}
The first summand by assumption is positive definite, while each of the other summands is positive semidefinite, because it is, up to a permutation of rows and columns, equal to a Kronecker product of the form
$$
\pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&1\\ &&0\\ &&&\ddots\\ &&&&0}\otimes W_{ij}.
$$
Hence $W$ is positive definite.